# Filter array of objects inside another array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Javascript. Have a structure like this, array of objects, that have array of `items` inside each

```
[
  {
    "title": "Venom",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "Venom title",
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "title": "Venom2",
        "active": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Video",
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "title": "Button",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "Button page",
        "active": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to exclude `items` with `active: false` property inside each element, so exclude element *Venom2*

```
{
   "title": "Venom2",
   "action": "venom2",
   "content": "qwertrete5t5t4t5",
   "active": false
}
```

from exists array.

I make it with forEach and accumulate array inside another, here it is

```
let menu = [];

v.forEach((section) => {
     menu.push({
         title: section.title,
         items: section.items.filter(item => item.active)
     })
});
```

Then I tried to make it more beautiful with double filter, but it's not working, it returns `[]`, and i basically guess why...

```
let menu = v.filter((section) => {
    return (section.items.filter(item => item.active === true));
});
```

Perhaps there are more beautiful (may be with reduce) decision of my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `forEach` should work fine. The only improvement I can see is to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). So that, you can directly assign it to `menu` like this:

```js
const v = [{title:"Venom",items:[{title:"Venom title",active:true},{title:"Venom2",active:false}]},{title:"Video",items:[]},{title:"Button",items:[{title:"Button page",active:true}]}];

let menu = v.map(({title, items}) => ({title, items: items.filter(i => i.active)}))
console.log(menu)
```